# How to capture image with HTML input on mobile browser and save photo to phone storage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mobile-browser

I need to save the mobile browser camera captured image to the phone storage(gallery). But I could not find a way to do it with simple HTML javascript, Or is there any special library that can help me to do this functionality on my mobile browser application? I'm using AngularJs

Comment: Browsers have a [Media Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API) you can use - you probably want to start at [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: Thanks, I checked this but I think this is not fully supported by all browsers.

Comment: so you need to support Opera Mini, UC Browser for Android, QQ Browser, Baidu Browse and KaiOS Browser?

Comment: I need to support IOS and Android almost for all browsers, but priorities are Chrome, Safari, Mozilla

Comment: and they all support capturing camera - I know, I have a PWA that works with the camera flawlessly in all those browsers (though, haven't tested Firefox on mobile devices recently since Firefox has abandoned PWA) - but PWA is another story